# Find the point of the plane $2x -y + z -2 = 0$ such that the sum of its distances to $P$ and $Q$ are the minimum

Tags: linear-algebra

I have find the point of the plane $2x -y + z -2 = 0$ such that the sum of its distances to $P$ and $Q$ are the minimum, where $P = (2,1,0)$ and $Q = (1,-1,-1)$

So by the equation of the distance from a point to a plane, we have:

$$d(B,\pi) = \frac{|\vec {AB}\cdot\vec n|}{\|\vec n\|}$$

$$\|\vec n\| = \sqrt{2^2 + (-1)^2 + 1^2} = \sqrt{6}$$
$$\vec {AP} = (2-x, 1-y, -z)$$
$$\vec {AQ} = (1-x, -1-y, -1-z)$$
*where $\vec n$ is the normal vector of the plane, $A$ is a point on the plane, and $B$ is the point outside of the plane (and of course $\pi$ is the plane)

I did this formula for $P$ and $Q$ and supposed a generic point $(x,y,z)$:

$$\frac{|(2-x, 1-y, -z).(2,-1,1)|}{\sqrt{6}} + \frac{|(1-x, -1-y, -1-z).(2,-1,1)|}{\sqrt{6}}$$

However, I don't know how to continue from here. I don't think I can find $(x,y,z)$ such that this this expression reaches its minimum. Maybe I'm doing the wrong way. Should I use the parametric equation of the plane? Then I would have two variables, but I still don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Call the desired point $R:=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. you want to minimize $|PR|+|RQ|$ subject to the constraint that $2x_0-y_0+z_0-2=0$. you do not need to know the distance from $P$ or $Q$ to the plane.

Comment: Won't that be computationally intensive?

Comment: It's an exercise meant to be simple, in my book of exercises

Answer (score 1):

Since the point Q belongs to the plane, it is obvious that in this case the point you are looking for is Q.

If this was not the case, you would be looking for the intersection of the plane with the line $PQ$. (Assuming P and Q lie in the different half-spaces given by the plane.)

The only more complicated case is when both P and Q are in the same half-space. In such case you might start by finding reflection P' of P w.r.t. the given plane.